# Batch file to save output between brackets to a new txt file

Tags: batch-file

I am running the following batch script to reverse lookup domain names form IPs

> For /f %%i in (c:\ip.txt) do (Ping -a %%i -n 1 >>output.txt )

The file ip.txt has a list of IPs in it.

The output file has an output like this which is expected

```
Pinging UKSEVRERNAME.com [10.87.130.200] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.87.130.200: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=53

Ping statistics for 10.87.130.200:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 16ms, Average = 16ms
```

What I want is to only keep the the server name and IP and disregard the rest...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say that you're wanting to reverse lookup domain names from IP's, and that those IP's are listed in a text file. Your question title however, says you're wanting to capture the output between the brackets. It shouldn't be too difficult to understand that each of the lines from your text file is the content between the brackets, so you already know that! What, you're seemingly wanting to do, is capture some content from any line which contains an open bracket, and, dependent upon any possible locale configuration, immediately followed by the text file line content.

Answer (score 3):

Attention. The following code is language-dependent:

```
For /f %%i in (ip.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('Ping -a %%i -n 1^|find "["') do echo %%a  %%i
)
```

This is valid for English Windows versions (`Pinging <Server> [<IP>] with 32 bytes of data:`)

You'll have to adapt `tokens` to your localization. For example a German Windows gives
`Ping wird ausgeführt für <Server> [<IP>] mit 32 Bytes Daten:`, so it would be `tokens=5`

If a hostname can not be resolved, this code will give no result for this host.

If you want to have the IP instead, change the `find` string to `find " 32 "` (note the spaces)

Answer (score 0):

In case you only need the line with servername and IP address, I'd advise you to add `| findstr "Pinging"` after your command, as you can see in this example:

```
ping -a 172.217.168.227 | findstr "Pinging"
Pinging ams15s40-in-f3.1e100.net [172.217.168.227] with 32 bytes of data:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('type ip.txt') do (
  for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=[] " %%b in ('ping %%a -n 1 ^| find "Pinging"') do (
  echo Server name: %%b
  echo IP address: %%c
  )
)
```